# GCP Equivalent of Azure Policies

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In Azure, it's possible to create a policy which, for instance, says *Port 80 is not allowed open to the Internet*.  Or *Only VMs of a certain size are allowed*.  Is there a GCP construct which prevents a certain set of rules to be broken?

My scenario would be a service principal with Owner rights over a project, but the SP cannot modify the "standard policies".

Comment: There is indeed the concept of organizational policies ... these can be found documented here:

https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/org-policy-constraints

Comment: Org policies doesnot seems to be working on granular level like azure policy. Can we write custom org policyin gcp ?